# How should Magento Varien JS Files be changed?

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7, prototypejs

I need to make some changes to the following Magento files:

- public_html\js\varien\configurable.js
- public_html\js\varien\product,js

The question is; should I be editing these files?
Are they core files (that will be replaced if I upgraded Magento)?

If I shouldn't be editing them, what should I do if I want to change the contents of these files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you want to override "reload" function of `product.js`

Follow the steps

-> Create a new folder under js folder, in our case under `/js/jsoverride/`

-> Now create a new js file, in our case we have created `/js/jsoverride/product.js` with the following code

> ```
> Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.reload 
>    = Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.reload.wrap(function(parentMethod){
>                  alert("Override success");
> });
> ```

-> Add the following code to the proper layout file(catalog.xml/local.xml)

> ```
>  <reference name="head">
>     <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
>     <action method="addJs"><script>jsoverride/product.js</script></action>
>         ......
>  </reference>
> ```

Flush the cache after your are done with your update.

More information see [wrap()](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/wrap/)

Comment: Note, you can also override with javascript in your theme... I find this much cleaner. ```<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>```

Comment: I want to override initPrices method. I am following same process said by you but it is not working.

Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.initPrices
   = Product.OptionsPrice.prototype.initPrices.wrap(function(parentMethod){
                 this.containers[5] = 'product-price-' + this.productId + '_clone';
});